# pnpm install - transitive dependency strict version (ignore caret)

Tags: npm, pnpm

Let us take a example, I want to install a new package (a@1.0.0) using pnpm. This package a@1.0.0 is dependent on package b@^1.0.0, and getting b's 1.2.0 (latest version). Is there an option to tell pnpm to strictly bring b's 1.0.0 and not use caret. I was using overrides but there are so many things to take care in different dependencies, so wanted to understand if there is simple way to tell pnpm for a package that takes care of all trasitive dependencies.